# MongoDB: как оптимизировать работу скрипта?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
function processRequests() {
    requestIds = db.validationResultProcessing.find(
        { status: "не обработано" }
    )
    .forEach(function (req) {
        var request = db.requests.findOne(
            { _id: req._id },
            { region: 1, validationResults: 1 }
        );
        print(request._id + " request began processing");
        if (request.validationResults != undefined) {
            request.validationResults.forEach(function (valRes) {
                var id = ObjectId();
                valRes._id = id.str;
                valRes.requestId = request._id;
                valRes.region = request.region;
                requestValidationResults.push(valRes);
            });
        }
        insertRequestValidationResults(requestValidationResults);
        updateValidationResultProcessing(request);
        print(request._id + " has processed");
    });

}
```

Данный код выбирает id записей из временной таблицы с пометкой "не обработанно", затем выбирает по id записи для обработки из основной таблицы. Основная проблема в том, что скрипт работает очень медленно. Непозволительно медленно. Как можно ускорить скрипт, при этом обеспечить транзакционность. Версия mongoDB 3.5. Пишите плз любые идеи как это оптимизировать